# CSS flexible box model and element heights

Tags: css

I'm using the flexible box module to position two `div` elements horizontally with the second `div` being flexible. To do so I'm using code similar to the following:

```
#container {
    display: -moz-box; -moz-box-orient: horizontal; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; }

#one, #two {
    background: rgb(230,235,240);
    padding: 20px;
}
#two {
    -moz-box-flex: 1; -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

The `#two` div is going to have more content than `#one` and, in turn, will likely always be taller. For some reason when using the flexible box module it extends the height of the `#one` div to match the height of `#two`. This isn't quite what I'm wanting. I need the `#one` div's height to be auto.

Suggestions on why this is happening, and/or how to fix it?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/3F7Vu/

And a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to set `box-align: start` for `#container`.

BTW, after adding standard properties without vendor prefix, your code will also work in IE10 and Opera.

Comment: Haha. Just found that fix. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

ACK. I can research for an hour and then post the question. IMMEDIATELY afterwards I figure it out.

```
-moz-box-align: start; -webkit-box-align: start; box-align: start;
```